# Can I serve a create react app from an express server without running 'npm run build'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a nodejs with express server. I would like to server a create react app from the server. Is this possible with out building the react app?

Example from a project im working on right now.

I server a built react app like this...

```
 //// Server static resources.
ROUTER.use('/static', EXPRESS.static(PATH.join(__dirname, '../', '../', 'project', 'build', 'static')));
//// Server built react app. 
ROUTER.get('/',  function(req, res) {        
    res.sendFile(  PATH.join(__dirname, '../', '../', 'project', 'build', 'index.html' ));
});
```

Any way I can server the react app without building it? Something like...

```
ROUTER.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //redirect to loopback port for react app. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a [project layout](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=node%20project%20layout) which suits you well.

Since you have client side and server side code, you could maintain two folders, each one containing module-specific code.

CLI tools like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) expects such approach to be adopted, unless your project uses some kind of [SSR](https://nextjs.org/features/server-side-rendering)

A reasonable good project layout looks like this:

```
my-project/
├── my-project-react/
│   ├── package.json 
│   ├── src/  
│   ├── (... other project files) 
│   └── README.md 
├── my-project-express/
│   ├── package.json 
│   ├── app/ 
│   ├── (... other project files) 
│   └── README.md 
├── .gitignore 
└── README.md
```

That way you can serve express with nodemon and react with webpack dev server, just remember to [enable cors on express](https://github.com/expressjs/cors). You also must adjust the service address inside your web app project, depending on NODE_ENV.

Comment: My project layout looks like that. Just have two react projects. One of them will use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

[crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) has a backend subproject based on Express that serves a sample React application (which is not CRA).

If you follow [Getting started](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) or alternatively execute commands:

- `git clone https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react.git`
- `cd crisp-react`
- `yarn install && yarn start:prod`
  Express is running...
  Terminate by `Control+C`

then you will have a running instance of Express serving a react app which you can see by pointing a browser to localhost:3000.  The backend/Express subproject only serves the React app, it doesn't build the app and in fact cannot build it because the backend doesn't have React library in its [package.json](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/server/package.json) as a dependency.